# Looping through many multiple regressions

Tags: r, loops, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to run this code from this post: [looping with iterations over two lists of variables for a multiple regression in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56813352/looping-with-iterations-over-two-lists-of-variables-for-a-multiple-regression-in/59195499?noredirect=1#comment104609123_59195499)
with modified variable and data frame names, because it seems to do exactly what I want and uses a very similar dataset. However, it keeps giving me an error and I don't know why, so I would really appreciate if someone could help me to understand the error or the corresponding line of code so I could try to figure out what's wrong.

```
for(i in 1:n) {
  vars = names(output)[names(output) %in% paste0(c(".PRE", ".POST"), i)]
  models[[as.character(i)]] = lm(paste("growth_rate ~ ", paste(vars, collapse=" +   ")),
                                 data = output)
}

Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: growth_rate ~  
   ^
```

My dataset looks almost like the one given in the above mentioned post besides the fact that my "RDPI_T" and "DRY_T" variables are in an alternating order (which I dont think matters in this case). The analogous variables I have are 69 PRE variables called id1.PRE, id2.PRE ... id69.PRE and also 69 POST variables called id1.POST, id2.POST ... id69.POST in the output dataset. Also, growth_rate is in the same dataset called output.

Additionally, I would also like to add 2 more independent variables that are regular and do not come from a list: country and year but I am unsure how to incorporate that here?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Looping through models to do Wald tests is statistical malpractice. You need statistical consultation in the worst way.

Comment: I am replicating a paper that has been cited more than 1000 times and published in The Quarterly Journal of Economics so I am not really questioning the statistics and instead I am trying  to find a way to do it. I am happy to hear your suggestions rather than life lessons about how badly I need statistical consultation.

Comment: Was there were an appropriate consideration of the multiple comparisons problem that arises from such a process?

Comment: They have not mentioned anything like that in the paper, I am afraid. But they came up with a single chi2 value and a p-value after running the 69 models. Basically they wanted to compare whether id.PRE is the same as id.POST (data explained in my previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59150321/create-lead-and-lag-year-dummies-for-regression-in-r) using the 69 regression models to get an overall conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your columns are called id1.PRE, id2.PRE, then the paste function you have above will not work, which most likely throws the error.

Please do `dput(head(output))` and paste the output, this allows us to see the column names and why it doesn't work.

Try something below,according to how you describe the column names:

```
#simulate data
output=data.frame(
"growth_rate"=rnorm(100),
matrix(rnorm(100*69*2),nrow=100)
)
colnames(output)[-1] = c(paste("id",1:69,".PRE",sep=""),paste("id",1:69,".POST",sep=""))
output$year = 1901:2000
output$country = sample(letters,nrow(output),replace=TRUE)

n=69
#create list to hold models
models = vector("list",n)

for(i in 1:n) {
  vars = paste0("id",i,c(".PRE", ".POST"))
# i think it works without as.formula, but better to be safe
  FORMULA = as.formula(paste("growth_rate ~ ", paste(vars, collapse=" +  ")))
  models[[i]] = lm(FORMULA,data = output)
}
```

If you want to include other variables:

```
for(i in 1:n) {
  vars = paste0("id",i,c(".PRE", ".POST"))
  # add other variables
  vars = c(vars,"country","year")
  FORMULA = paste("growth_rate ~ ", paste(vars, collapse=" +  "))
  models[[i]] = lm(FORMULA,data = output)
}
```

Comment: Using the newly created models, I am trying to run a Wald test but it does not seem to work on the 69 models at the same time only when I choose to do a Wald test for a single model from the list. Any ideas by any chance? `#install.packages("aod")
library(aod)
wald.test(b = coef(models[[1]]), Sigma = vcov(models[[1]]), Terms = 1:2) #this one works only
wald.test(b = coef(models), Sigma = vcov(models,Terms = 1:2)) #this one does not work`